# Как создать зеркальную ссылку с объекта на объект?

Tags: python, django

Для магазина мне нужно реализовать рекомендованные продукты под продуктом. Т.е. у меня есть две модели: Product (собственно сам продукт) и RecommendedProduct (рекомендованные продукты, т.е. продукты которые по какому-то принципу подходят выбранному продукту). RecommendedProduct связан с Product через ForeignKey.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать следующую функциональность. Когда я вбиваю УРЛ рекомендованного продукта под выбранным продуктом, чтоб под рекомендованным продуктом создался рекомендованный продукт с линкой на выбранный продукт:

1. Есть Product#1.
2. Я создаю Product#2 и под этим продуктом я хочу сделать рекомендованным продуктом Product#1.
3. Я вбиваю в рекомендованный продукт (под Product#2) УРЛ продукта Product#1.
4. Мне нужно, чтоб зеркально под Product#1 создался рекомендованный продукт который ссылается на Product#2

Есть две модели:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name=u"Название товара")

class RecommendedProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name=u"Рекомендуемый товар", related_name="recommended_product")
    recommended_product_slug = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=u"значение slug параметра рекомендуемого товара")
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную функциональность?

Comment: Возможно [это](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) или [это](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно реализовать ManyToMany Связь между продуктами . 
В рекомендованом продукте убрать ForeignKey
И создать еще одну модель

```
class ProductManyToMany(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='recommend_product')
        recommend_product = models.ForeignKey(recommended_product, related_name='product')
```

После вы создаете оба продукта , и потом создаете объект типа ProductManyToMany куда и подставляете ваши продукты

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, null=True)`

```
class Product(models.Model):
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True) 
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name=u"Название товара")
        recommended_products = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, null=True)
```

Подробно в документации можно найти тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

Answer (score 0):

Вижу решение в виде ещё одной модели с тегами, а также методе который предоставляет N-последних рекомендованых продуктов

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24, null=False, blank=False)

    def get_recommendations(self, limit=5, offset=0):
        """
        Возвращает выборку с рекомендоваными товарами
        """
        selected_tags = models.Subquery(
            self.productrecommendation_set.values('tag_id'),
        )

        # Метод можно расширить добавив проверку товаров на наличие
        recommendation_set = ProductRecommendation.objects.filter(
            tag__in=selected_tags,
        ).values('product')[offset:limit]

        return recommendation_set

class RecommendTag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=24, null=False, blank=False)


class ProductRecommendation(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey('RecommendTag', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ON_CASCADE — удаляет запись если был удален товар/тег

    @classmethod
    def update_recommendation(cls, tag_title, products_seq=tuple()):
        """
        Возвращаем и при необходимости создаем тег для похожих продуктов
        """

        tag, is_created = RecommendTag.objects.get_or_create(
            title=tag_title,
            defaults={'title': tag_title},
        )

        if is_created:
            tag.save()

        # Добавляем записи рекомендаций к тегу
        # Существующие записи не удаляются
        cls.objects.bulk_create(
            map(
                lambda x: cls(tag=tag, product=x),
                products_seq,
            ),
            # Пропускаем записи где тег и продукт — повторяются
            ignore_conflicts=True,  
        )
        return tag

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('tag', 'product'),  # запрещаем создавать одинаковые записи
        )
```

P.S.: Не используйте M2M без необходимости — с ним генерируются крайне медленные запросы.